# ConfigParser won't save changes made to values in .ini file

Tags: python, ini, configparser

first up, please forgive me if I'm making an obvious mistake, I'm very new to this lol.

I've made a little trivia game for me and my friends and I'm trying to keep a scoreboard using Configparser. Currently, what I think I'm doing is when someone gets a question correct, I read the file called scoreboard.ini grab that person's score add 1 to it and then rewrite the file. My issue is that the changes to the file don't save. When I run it and later call the scores it gives me the original unedited version and opening the file itself also shows that nothing has changed.

```
with open(r'/filepath/scoreboard.ini','r+') as files:
         config.read((r'/filepath/scoreboard.ini'))
         print(config.getint('scores','playerA')) ### returns 0 which is correct
         PlayerA_Score = config.getint('scores','PlayerA_Score') + 1
         print(PlayerA_Score) ### returns 1 - working correctly
with open(r'/filepath/scoreboard.ini','w+') as files:
         config.write(files)
         config.set('scores', 'playerA', PlayerA_Score)
         print(config.getint('scores', 'playerA')) ### also returns 1 - still working up to here
         os.rename('scoreboard.ini','scoreboard.ini')
```

So up to here, it seems to be working fine, when I print out the values. Yet if I open the scoreboard file it still has the original values.

Also worth mentioning I'm renaming the file as the same thing cause that was one potential solution I saw suggested elsewhere, but it hasn't worked. Previously I was just closing the file at that point instead.

I've also tried having two files, scoreboard which I open and read the values from and then writing a new file called scoreboardA where I write the updated scores values to. Then renaming scoreboardA to scoreboard and renaming scoreboard to something else. Another potential solution I saw online that didn't work and honestly just confused me.

I'm really at my wits end with this one lol and only have like 3 weeks of coding under my belt so any help would be very appreciated. Apologies again if this is a simple question I couldn't find a solution anywhere.

Other potentially relevant information:

- I am doing this for a bot I'm making for discord using discord.py
- I am working in Pycharm
- I am on a mac

If you need any other information please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally realized what I was doing wrong. It seems I misunderstood what config.write() does lol. I needed to open the file, change the values using set and then use write() to save that to my file. My amended code is.

```
with open(r'/filepath/scoreboard.ini','r+') as files:
     config.read((r'/filepath/scoreboard.ini'))
     print(config.getint('scores','playerA')) 
     PlayerA_Score = config.getint('scores','PlayerA_Score') + 1
     print(PlayerA_Score)
     config.set('scores', 'playerA', PlayerA_Score)
     print(config.getint('scores', 'playerA')) 
with open(r'/filepath/scoreboard.ini','w+') as files:
     config.write(files)
```

I might still be misunderstanding something but my code works so maybe this will fix it for anyone else having a similar issue! :)